# Could not detect boost libraries when configuring Bitcoin core - Apple M1 Mac Mini

Tags: mac, compiling

I´m trying to install Bitcoin from source on an Apple M1 Mac Mini (Big Sur 11.2.3) and Im getting this when running

```
./configure --prefix=$PWD/depends/arm-apple-darwin20.3.0
```

"We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.58.0 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option."

config.log tells me:

```
configure:32586: checking for boostlib >= 1.58.0 (105800)
configure:32618: g++ -std=c++17 -c -g -O2 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DMAC_OSX -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -DPROVIDE_FUZZ_MAIN_FUNCTION  conftest.cpp >&5
conftest.cpp:73:10: fatal error: 'boost/version.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/version.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
configure:32618: $? = 1
```

I have boost installed via homebrew in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost
(Version 1.75.0) and I did try

```
export BOOST_ROOT=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost
```

before building, but keep getting the same result.

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/include"
```

also didnt help. Any ideas very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Rosetta 2 was missing on the new system I set up. If anyone else runs into the same problem:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

does the trick. Thanks to @AlgorithmicRisk on Twitter for pointing this out.

Comment: FYI fanquake has put up some cross compiled (minus Qt) binaries using depends for Apple M1 hardware here: https://github.com/fanquake/build_artifacts/releases/tag/m1_test

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it turns out that my system was missing the Boost library.

Install it using this(on wsl): sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Then it should work.